# how to drag and drop from 1 div on top of of the background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

http://i39.tinypic.com/10xyi3c.png

Refer to image link above. I am trying to do a drag and drop of each and every of the 4 items on the left into the canvas on the right. The 4 items are in one div and the canvas is in another div.

After i drag the icons it seems to be behind the background image. Refer to the image below.

http://i44.tinypic.com/t0kcx0.png

What should i do?

The following are my codes for the file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Daisy</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style1.css">


<!-- CALLING THE DRAG AND DROP FUNCTION -->

<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
}
</script>



</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header"><input name="save" type="button" class="save" value="Save"  width=60% height=60%>
  <img src="_assets/title.png" width=60% height=60 %>

  </div>




  <!--       PLEASE DO SOME RESEARCH ON HOW TO BRING THE DRAG PICTURE(e.g pot,soil,opp etc etc FORWARD     -->
  <!--       ALSO, HOW TO BRING THE BACKGROUND PICTURE BACKWARDS -->


 <div id="subNav"><img src="_assets/pot.png" id="pot1" alt="pot" width=100% height=100% ondragstart="drag(event)" draggable="true" class="icons">
                   <img src="_assets/soil.png" id="soil1" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="soil" width=100% height=100% draggable="true" class="icons">
                   <img src="_assets/opp.png" id="can1" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="wateringcan" width=100% height=100% draggable="true" class="icons">
                   <img src="_assets/Crazy_daisy.png"   id="seed1" ondragstart="drag(event)" alt="seeds" width=100% height=100% draggable="true" class="icons">                   
  </div>






                  <!-- DRAG AND DROP INTO DESIGNATRED AREA-->
      <div id="content" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"><img src="_assets/background.png" width=95% height=95% alt="bg">
                        <img src="_assets/instructions.png" alt="instructions" width=25% height=25% class="instructions">
      </div>






</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle so we can test

Comment: Fiddle of the question:http://jsfiddle.net/n5taH/

Comment: @The_Unknown did you even look at the fiddle

Comment: i've made the fiddle from the code above so other people can use it

Comment: Take a look ad this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop    It might help you

Comment: i drag the icon in but i couldnt see my icon appear on the background image.i guess it went below the image. but i tried using the z index but there was no change in the website.